# How to catch the MethodNotFoundException exception inside the class?

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection

Suppose we a have class named `DynamicClass`:

```
public class DynamicClass {

    public void get(String input) {
        System.out.println(input);
    }

}
```

Now, imagine the following instantiating of `DynamicClass`:

```
DynamicClass clazz = new DynamicClass();
clazz.getName();
clazz.getOther();
```

Of course, the calling of `getName` and `getOther` methods throws `MethodNotFoundException` exception. However, I'm curious, is there any way to catch the `MethodNotFoundException` exception inside the `DynamicClass` class, i.e. the calling of `get("Name")` and `get("Other")` rather than throwing the `MethodNotFoundException` exception due to the calling of `getName()` and `getOther()`?

Comment: That won't happen in Java. But I think defining such a "default" method would be possible in a dynamic language like Groovy: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Respond_to_an_unknown_method_call#Groovy

Comment: Isn't this a compile time, error, instead of being a runtime exception. Calling some method that is not there... !!!! Ahha, I didn't knew about Reflections as yet @MarounMaroun  :( Happy to know, I can read somethingy new :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw Using reflection it won't be an error. Things are dynamic there.

Comment: @MarounMaroun But the OP isn't using reflection.

Comment: I fail to understand why this is not a compile time error? Did you mean the following ? Class clazz = DynamicClass.class;   clazz.getMethod("getName");

Comment: @AnjithKumarPaila no, please check this link: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Respond_to_an_unknown_method_call to get my purpose

Comment: @yaa110 Yes, but that's not possible in java as java is statically typed language. As other folks said you can do it in Groovy or any other dynamically typed language(may be not all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879038/android-exceptions-without-force-close), it's possible to catch all uncaught Exceptions in [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)):

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
        // TODO
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice curiosity.

I am afraid, there is no other way than using try catch in Java, but if Java was a OTF(on the fly) compiler and the exception mechanism actually use a (if-responds_to?) method which expected to be declared on the top of the hierarchal pyramid of Class inheritance for example Object in Java that would be possible to override that method on your DynamicClass.

However Java doesn't use the above mechanism to control the if responds_to? and the messages which are sent to an object(class) are tested somewhere else in compiler but not as a method that you can override.

I know a language called (Magik) that has the above mechanism which is very nice and it is an OTF compiler.

the Object class in Magik has a method with name does_not_responds_to() and whenever a message is sent to an object it is tested against the class states and behaviors and finally raise or better to say run does_not_responds_to() method in case the method name(message) is invalid.

It is a very neat solution to implement the does_not_responds_to? method in the class (DynamicClass) to handle the exception before it raises. however after 10 years of experiance with Magik, never needed to do so.

Sorry, My English is not good, I hope I could explain the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
try{
   clazz.getName();
   clazz.getOther();
}catch(MethodNotFoundException e){
   clazz.get("Name")
}
```

But actually do not think that it is good idea...

Comment: This is not what OP is looking for, he's referring reflection, the class is dynamic. Their code is just for illustrating the problem.

Comment: @MarounMaroun The OP hasn't said anything about using reflection.